# convert html into javascript string

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs

I'm getting some html from node-request and I want to place that html into my javascript code as strings:

```
<div id='frontpage'><div set-href="'/user/' + (user | encodeURIComponent)">userlink</div></div>
```

The goal is to get an output like this for angularjs:

```
var createCache = function (path, template) {
  return "\n  $templateCache.put('" + path + "',\n    '" +template + "'\n  );\n";
}
```

This code is too naive, there are issues with quotes and other potential problems. How could it be done correctly? Is there a way to get the string from node-request itself? Thanks.

Comment: As for issues with quotes, have you tried using the `escape()` method?

Comment: @NickDugger that's not what I want. I need escaping like this: `\'` not `%27`

Comment: Well, you could do some simple `.replace(/"/g, "\"")` or some regex, which I never wrapped my head around, myself.

Comment: @NickDugger thanks man, but i'd rather not. regexes on html is rarely a great idea